# Reload jsp and lose request.getParameter("...") on servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, request, httpsession

I have 2 jsp-page. In first jsp-page I use combobox who choosing subject, several radio button for action. On servlet this page I get `request.getParameter("subjectID")`.

Better If I show servlets and jsp

```
<form  action="/TutorWebApp/controller" method="POST" name="editTestForm">
                <p>
                    Choose subject 
                    <select name='subject'>
                        <c:forEach items="${subjects}" var="subject" >                  
                            <option value="${subject.key}">
                                ${subject.value.getName()}
                            </option>                    
                        </c:forEach>
                    </select>  
                </p>                
                <input type="radio" name="command" value="add_test">
                Add test <br />
                <input type="radio" name="command" value="add_subject">
                Add subject <br />                
                <input type="submit" value="OK"/>                 
            </form>
```

In this page I choose subject from combobox. And choose "Add test". After I go to servlet where

```
class AddTestCommand implements Command {

    private static final String PARAM_TEST_NAME = "testName";
    private static final String PARAM_SUBJECT = "subject";

    @Override
    public String execute(HttpServletRequest request) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String page = " ";
        String message = " ";        

        String testName = request.getParameter(PARAM_TEST_NAME);


        if (testName != null && (!"".equals(testName))) {

            HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
            Integer userID = (Integer) session.getAttribute("userID");


            Integer subjectId = 
                    Integer.valueOf(request.getParameter(PARAM_SUBJECT));

            if(AddTestLogic.addTest(userID, subjectId, testName)){
               message = "Success";
            } else{
               message = "This test already exist"; 
            }        

            request.setAttribute("result", message);
        }       


        page = ResourceBuilder.getPropertyManager(PropertyEnum.JSP_PAGE).
                getProperty("path.page.addtest");
        return page;
    }
}
```

There I can get value of subject as `request.getParameter("subject");` near with testName before if(){} And next step  - go to next jsp

```
<form  action="/TutorWebApp/controller" method="POST" name="addTestForm">   
            <input type="hidden" name="command" value="add_test" />            
            Name of new test:
            <input type="text" name="testName" value=""/>            
            <input type="submit" value="Add test"/>            
</form>
```

An after input data in jsp I go to the same servlet again. But I lose value request.getParameter("subject").

I try to use HttpSession but on first page I send Map. And get with request just choosen subjectID from Map.

I don't know how resolve this problem.
Thanks

Comment: Just add another hidden field with that name and value?

Comment: @BalusC on jsp with textField? as `<input type="hidden" name="subjectID" value="${subject}" />`

Comment: @BalusC I don't ubderstand... Can you help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can retain request parameters for the next request with a hidden field. Request parameters are available by the `${param}` map in EL. So, this should do:

```html
<input type="hidden" name="subject" value="${fn:escapeXml(param.subject)}" />
```

Note that I'm using [JSTL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info) `fn:escapeXml()` to escape HTML entities; this will prevent possible [XSS attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting).

Comment: Hi @BalusC, thank you. I wonder though why this does not work (_the confirm dialog does not get prompted to retain request params_) when an endUser hits "Enter" key on the URL to reload the page instead of pressing "F5" or clicking "Refresh"' navigator's button ?